# Add a scrollball in mxGraph

Tags: css, xml, scrollbar, diagramming, mxgraph

I am using mxGraph in my application, and I want to add a scrollbar in the swimlane A, in order to be able to show the different nodes.

The sweimlane A is defined as:

```html
<mxCell id="2" value="A" style="swimlane;fillColor=#A0A0A0  " parent="1" vertex="1">
    <mxGeometry x="80" y="130" width="890" height="550" as="geometry"/>
</mxCell>
```

I will be thankful for any help.

[image]

Comment: If you are using div ,then make overflow as auto(<div style='overflow:scroll;'). In case if you are using some framework, then please do mention here. It would be helpful if you can post, how you are rendering mxgraph.

Answer (score 0):

Containers in mxGraph do not support scrollbars.